# How do I properly implement async/await for image data migration?

Tags: c#, async-await

I'm writing a console app to do some data migration between a legacy system and a new version. Each record has associated images stored on one web server and I'm downloading/altering/uploading each image to Azure (and also recording some data about each image in a database).

Here's a rough outline, in code:

```
public void MigrateData()
{
    var records = GetRecords();

    foreach (var record in records)
    {
        // ...

        MigrateImages(record.Id, record.ImageCount);
    }
}

public void MigrateImages(int recordId, int imageCount)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= imageCount; i++)
    {
        var legacyImageData = DownloadImage("the image url");

        if (legacyImageData != null && legacyImageData.Length > 0)
        {
            // discard because we don't need the image id here, but it's used in other workflows
            var _ = InsertImage(recordId, legacyImageData);
        }
    }
}

// This method can be used elsewhere, so the return of int is necessary and cannot be changed
public int InsertImage(int recordId, byte[] imageData)
{
    var urls = UploadImage(imageData).Result;

    return // method call to save image and return image ID
}

public async Task<(Uri LargeUri, Uri ThumbnailUri)> UploadImage(byte[] imageData)
{
    byte[] largeData = ResizeImageToLarge(imageData);
    byte[] thumbnailData = ResizeImageToThumbnail(imageData);

    var largeUpload = largeBlob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(largeImage, 0, largeImage.Length);
    var thumbUpload = thumbsBlob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(thumbImage, 0, thumbImage.Length);

    await Task.WhenAll(largeUpload, thumbUpload);

    var largeUrl = "";// logic to build url
    var thumbUrl = "";// logic to build url

    return (largeUrl, thumbUrl);
}
```

I'm using async/await for `UploadImage()` to allow parallel uploads for the large and thumbnail images, saving time.

My question is (if it's possible/makes sense) how can I utilize async/await for `MigrateImages()` to do parallel image uploads in order to reduce the overall time it takes for the task to complete? Does the fact that I'm already using async/await within `UploadImage()` hinder my goal?

It might be obvious due to my question, but await/async is still something I can't fully wrap my head around about how to correct utilize and/or implement it.

Comment: `InsertImage` should be async and await `UploadImage` instead of calling `Result`. When `InsertImage` is async you can run multiple "inserts" by using the same pattern in `MigrateImages` as you do in `UploadImage` => start multiple async operations and await them with `Task.WhenAll`

Comment: The word "upload" would imply that you are I/O limited, not CPU limited. You need to determine if parallelization will benefit you. If the bottleneck is network speed, throwing more data into the bottleneck isn't going to speed anything up.

Comment: @DanielMann I'm trying to parallelize the process of uploading the images. Uploading 10 images "at the same time" should be faster than in serial, yes?

Comment: No. If you can upload 1 MB per second, and you're already uploading 1 MB per second, uploading two files at once means you're uploading at 1 MB per second, 500 KB per second per file. Or some other ratio that adds up to 1 MB/s.

Comment: @DanielMann understood, thanks for the clarification. For this example, we can assume upload bandwidth is not a limitation.

Answer (score 0):

The `async`/`await` technology is intended for facilitating asynchrony, not concurrency. In your case you want to speed-up the images-uploading process by uploading multiple images concurrently. It is not important if you are wasting some thread-pool threads by blocking them, and you have no UI thread that needs to remain unblocked. You are making a tool that you are going to use once or twice and that's it. So I suggest that you spare yourself the trouble of trying to understand why your app is not behaving the way you expect, and avoid `async`/`await` altogether. Stick with the simple and familiar synchronous programming model for this assignment.

Combining synchronous and asynchronous code is dangerous, and even more so if your experience and understanding of `async`/`await` is limited. There are many intricacies in this technology. Using the [`Task.Result`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task-1.result) property in particular is a red flag. When you become more proficient with `async`/`await` code, you are going to treat any use of `Result` like a an unlocked grenade, ready to explode in your face at any time, and make you look like a fool. When used in apps with synchronization context (Windows Forms, ASP.NET) it can introduce deadlocks so easily that [it's not even funny](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

Here is how you can achieve the desired concurrency, without having to deal with the complexities of asynchrony:

```
public (Uri LargeUri, Uri ThumbnailUri) UploadImage(byte[] imageData)
{
    byte[] largeData = ResizeImageToLarge(imageData);
    byte[] thumbnailData = ResizeImageToThumbnail(imageData);

    var largeUpload = largeBlob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(
        largeImage, 0, largeImage.Length);
    var thumbUpload = thumbsBlob.UploadFromByteArrayAsync(
        thumbImage, 0, thumbImage.Length);

    Task.WaitAll(largeUpload, thumbUpload);

    var largeUrl = "";// logic to build url
    var thumbUrl = "";// logic to build url

    return (largeUrl, thumbUrl);
}
```

I just replaced `await Task.WhenAny` with `Task.WaitAll`, and removed the wrapping `Task` from the method's return value.

Comment: Thanks, but you didn't actually answer the question - my code isn't working unexpectedly, I'm looking for ways to improve upon it.

Even though your suggestion of shying away from async/await is fine, your code doesn't do anything more than what I already have. There is no performance gain.

Comment: @Matt your code already performs concurrent uploads. Adding asynchrony to the mix will not make it faster. If you are asking for suggestions about how to make it faster, I would suggest to start by measuring the duration of uploading two files sequentially, and then two files concurrently. Then measure the duration of downloading and uploading one file sequentially, and then downloading and uploading one file concurrently. Give us these results and we may be able to help!